# How to close firefox service from putty?

Tags: linux, unix, java, putty, firefox

How can i close firefox service from putty??

I have tried using service command.. But i don't know the exact syntax..

I am getting following warning box

```
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must     first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

Please help me out to close firefox and open it again throug putty.....

thanks in advance....

Comment: What command did you use exactly?

Comment: Firefox service? This question probably doesn't belong on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the firefox 'pid' with the command:

```
ps -ef | grep -i firefox
```

it should give output of at least 2 lines, one of which is your 'grep' command, the other should be the running firefox processes. you can kill these with:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

is the 2nd number on the line, the 3rd number on the line is the parent pid, if there are more then 2 lines in the first command, try to find the parent pid all processes are pointing to and kill that one.

Comment: I got following reply when I executed

Comment: [root@OpsConsole firefox]# ps -ef | grep -i firefox
root      8609  8571  0 Oct14 pts/3    00:05:55 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
root     26812 12673  0 16:17 pts/5    00:00:00 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
root     26858 12613  0 16:19 pts/4    00:00:00 grep -i firefox

Comment: Can you please tell me the kill command now?????? @Flash

Comment: Just use `killall firefox`. If that fails, `killall -9 firefox`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your distribution, the following command will probably do it:

> pkill firefox

If not, try:

> pgrep -fl firefox

to get the process ID of firefox, and then:

> kill PID

where PID is the process ID.

Comment: GLad to help! Please mark the answer as correct :)